# How to use putString with firebase-php library?

Tags: php, firebase

I'm trying to use kreait/firebase-php for storing base64 images on Firebase. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310147/upload-a-base64-image-with-firebase-storage) I found a solution to upload base64 to Firebase but unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to this with the firebase-php library. How can I use it with the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do it. It seems just replacing "'data:image/jpeg;base64," and turning spaces to "+" and writing to a file directly is working fine.

Here is an example code.

```
$firebase = (new Firebase\Factory)
            ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
            ->create();


$storage = $firebase->getStorage();
$bucket = $storage->getBucket();

$base64Img = $base64Img->encoded;  // your base64 encoded string
$base64Img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $base64Img);
$base64Img = str_replace(' ', '+', $base64Img);

$object = $bucket->upload(base64_decode($base64Img), [
   'name' => $imageName
]);
```